# Parent view controller calling itself instead of child

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I am (trying to) implement a main view controller container to first instantiate the introduction view controller then the actual application view controller later.  But I am unable to get it to work and I feel I am missing something really basic.  The introduction view controller loads in the introduction view in the initWithFrame:

Using the following interface:

```
@interface ViewControllerMain : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewControllerIntroduction *viewControllerIntroduction;
@end
```

And the following implementation of

```
@implementation ViewControllerMain

- (void)loadView
{
    //  Instantiate the view controller for the adventure view
    self.viewControllerIntroduction = [ [ [ ViewControllerIntroduction alloc] init ] autorelease ];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [ super viewDidLoad ];

    //  Instantiate the view controller for the introduction view
    [ self addChildViewController: self.viewControllerIntroduction ];
    [ self.view addSubview: self.viewControllerIntroduction.view ];
    [ self.viewControllerIntroduction didMoveToParentViewController: self ];
}

@end
```

When I step past the addSubView statement, it steps back to the addChildViewController statement.

I've been trying to work this out for hours and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be overriding the `-loadView` method only if you are explicitly creating the view of your view controller (`self.view`). Remove your `-loadView` method and move the initialization of `self.viewControllerIntroduction` to `-viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Did I miss something by over-riding the -loadView method?  Does this explicitly entail that you only over-ride the -loadView in a view controller if that view controller contains an actual view?

Comment: `self.view` is initialised automatically in the UIViewController class' `-loadView` method... If you override it in your subclass, you should explicitly initialise it `self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame...]`. Also, no matter you are building a container view controller it also has a view.